# Problem using MOVE instead of XCOPY because contents do not move over

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have amended a batch script that almost does what i need it to do. It is intended take a directory source contents and create 10 sub-directories in a destination directory. It then split the contents by order of 100 folders into those 10 sub-directories. This works! however it is slow and i actually don't need to XCOPY them, I would rather MOVE the folders.

The problem comes when i replace the function XCOPY with MOVE. everything works the same apart from there is no contents in the created sub-directories

i want to know if there is a way to further amend this batch script so that it moves folders and their respective sub-folders (&files) rather than XCOPY them because its slow?

```
@ECHO OFF
title variable
SET source= Default
echo This tool will split folders contents into
echo Paste Directory here THEN type \ THEN press Enter:
SET /p source=
 cd %source%
SET destination= Default
echo paste Destination directory here THEN type \ THEN press Enter:
SET /p destination=
 cd %destination%
SET dcount=0
SET fcount=0
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

MKDIR %destination%dir%dcount%


FOR /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('DIR /b /a:d "%source%*"') do (
  MKDIR %destination%dir!dcount!\%%f
  XCOPY %source%%%f %destination%dir!dcount!\%%f /e /y 
  SET /a fcount=!fcount!+1
  IF !fcount! EQU 100 (
    SET fcount=0
    SET /a dcount=!dcount!+1
    MKDIR %destination%dir!dcount!
  )
)

ECHO DONE.
```

This does the job but I want it to MOVE instead of XCOPY, i tried replacing XCOPY with move but it just created 10 folders with no contents.  I then looked at the MOVE function in greater detail but it seems that it is better at moving files rather than folders and their sub-folders and contents?

Comment: You were told before, _[in your now deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57391934)_, about the use of doublequotes, if you weren't sure what I meant, you should have asked instead of deleting the question, and asking it again!

Comment: `move` has got no `/E` option, hence you cannot just replace `xcopy`; have you tried adding `rmdir /S /Q %source%%%f` just after `xcopy`? Anyway, I cannot reproduce that `move` skips sub-directories; I believe `move`, when providing just a source directory, does nothing but renaming it...

Comment: so I have tried it again with the MOVE and it does work however when it moves the folder it seems to put it inside another folder of the same name which is not what i want.

Answer (score 1):

This finally worked for me using the MOVE, we realised that this line `MKDIR %destination%dir!dcount!\%%f` which was nested above MOVE (or XCOPY in previous version) was creating another file within the files that were being moved. Once removed, the file structure was moved correctly and its contents instantly.

```
@ECHO ON
title variable
SET source= Default
echo This tool will split folders contents into
echo Paste Directory here THEN type \ THEN press Enter:
SET /p source=
 cd %source%
SET destination= Default
echo paste Destination directory here THEN type \ THEN press Enter:
SET /p destination=
 cd %destination%
SET dcount=0
SET fcount=0
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

MKDIR %destination%dir%dcount%


FOR /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('DIR /b /a:d "%source%*"') do (
  MOVE %source%%%f %destination%dir!dcount!\%%f 
  SET /a fcount=!fcount!+1
  IF !fcount! EQU 100 (
    SET fcount=0
    SET /a dcount=!dcount!+1
    MKDIR %destination%dir!dcount!
  )
)

ECHO DONE.
```

Now when run what this will ask is to paste the directory you want to split and enter a \ in order to close the directory, when Enter is pressed it will ask you to paste the destination for which you want the split folders to be nested in their created sub-folders  (dir0, dir,1 dir,2 etc...) and each of these will fill to 100 sub folders

Answer (score 0):

You could try ROBOCOPY as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/829636/xcopy-move-files-instead-of-copy), you would need the MOVE switch rather than MOV as you are moving folders, not files.

Comment: don't forget to /E instead of /S as well

Comment: I'm pretty dumb with windows scripting, I'm a .Net dev mostly  so excuse my stupidity - what is the /E flag for and which /S flag did you mean? :)

Comment: @Ryan: `/S` = "Subfolders (recursive), if not empty", `/E` = "Subfolders (recursive), even if empty".

Comment: @aschipfl Which bit was wrong sorry? I will change it, thanks

Comment: @Ryan, to find out how to use most internal commands and Microsoft executables, open a Command Prompt window and enter the command followed by`/?` i.e.`move /?`, `xcopy /?`, `robocopy /?` etc.

Comment: Neither `move` nor `copy` ignore zero-byte files; `copy` is just not capable of copying directory trees, but `move` is able to move such; as I stated in another comment, I cannot reproduce the described behaviour of `move`, so I guess the problem is something else (maybe bad/missing quotation, wrongly defined variables)...

Comment: Fair enough, I have edited, although I got the info about COPY ignoring zero byte files from the MS docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy

Comment: "Copying zero-length files

Copy does not copy files that are 0 bytes long. Use xcopy to copy these files."

Comment: I just noticed that is actually Windows Server docs which are probably different, I just did a quick search before answering and it worked for him so didn't look any further. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Look dude, I don't know what your issue is today - He is posting stuff on here for help, and also messaging me. When I found the answer I put it on here to help other people. He accepted it because it works. I never hid the fact I know him. Could you just back off please.

Comment: @Ryan, perhaps the statement concerning zero-byte files was true back in MS-DOS times, but nowadays it is not, I successfully copied empty files in both binary (`/B`) and in text (`/A`) mode, also with directories specified as source and destination, just like the situation of the question; seems you have found an error in the documentation then...

Comment: Cool, ok, thank you for explaining it. I have just told him to strip it right back to the example script he started modifying earlier and work forward as he had the xcopy command working ok eventually. As you say it is probably a syntax issue. I'm just on the sidelines trying to be supportive and let him find his way as this is kind of his first programming exercise. I've removed that chunk from my answer anyways.

Comment: I should clarify - he is still having issues using robocopy, so I have asked him to unaccept my answer, strip back the script and work forward, and then post a simple solution once he gets it working for other users to see in the future. This is his first day on SO and I am trying to gently guide him.